# WSo2 APIM getting error 401 trying to generate keys

Tags: oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am getting the following error when I try generate keys for a created application in the WSO2 API Manager, not sure why or how do I resolve this. I have WSO2 AM running on seperate instances than the gateways and KM node, everything else seems fine so far just errors when I try go through the key generation wizard or generate them manually:

````
TID: [-1234] [api/am/store] [2021-06-14 08:21:59,124] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager} - Cannot create OAuth application  : wso2useradmin_DefaultApplication_PRODUCTION org.wso2.carbon.apim
gt.impl.kmclient.KeyManagerClientException: Received status code: 401 Reason:
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KMClientErrorDecoder.decode_aroundBody0(KMClientErrorDecoder.java:29)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KMClientErrorDecoder.decode(KMClientErrorDecoder.java:27)
        at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy480.createApplication(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication_aroundBody0(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:97)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:154)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:125)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication_aroundBody6(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:118)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:78)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:66)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute_aroundBody0(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration_aroundBody146(APIConsumerImpl.java:4262)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:4094)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:545)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.ApplicationsApi.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApi.java:126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```
````

Comment: Whats the APIM version? Are you using the default key manager or have you configured another one?

Comment: APIM version is 3.2.0 and its the default key manager

Comment: Can you add the whole error stack here? Looks like the first part is missing

Comment: Apologies my formatting of the code block was wrong, have updated it so you can see the first line

Comment: Did you try with an application other than DefaultApplication?

Comment: Yes I did, created my own and tried. Still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

As per the shared trace, the API Manager was not able to authenticate with the (401) Key Manager component to register a client.

```
TID: [-1234] [api/am/store] [2021-06-14 08:21:59,124] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager} - Cannot create OAuth application  : wso2useradmin_DefaultApplication_PRODUCTION org.wso2.carbon.apim
gt.impl.kmclient.KeyManagerClientException: Received status code: 401 Reason:
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KMClientErrorDecoder.decode_aroundBody0(KMClientErrorDecoder.java:29)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KMClientErrorDecoder.decode(KMClientErrorDecoder.java:27)
        at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy480.createApplication(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication_aroundBody0(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:97)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:154)
```

This can be due to misconfigured username and password in the TOML configurations. If you have changed the super admin credentials, please do verify the following configurations are updated with the correct set of credentials in your environment

```
[apim.key_manager]
username = "superadmin-username"
password = "superadmin-password"
```

Either update the above-mentioned configurations with the correct set of credentials or comment on both `username` and `password` configurations to pick the super admin credentials on their own with the default mappings (since you are having the Key Manager in the same node as the Devportal).

Please try out the suggested approach and let us know